# Cookies value is too big it gave 400 response cos of cookie holds too much value

Tags: javascript, cookies, timer, store

I'm working on a timer and when a user stops the time it updates the cookie with the new time. Eventually the data in the cookie got so big 'cos of the amount of times in it, it gave me a 400 response, saying the data of the cookie is overloaded.

I don't want people who visit it receive a 400 and not know how to delete their cookies etc.

I use the cookie to retrieve their data when they come back a few days later and still have their achieved times.

Is there a way to do this more efficient? Holding more data in a cookie? Or better said: 'save' more data in cookies to retrieve them later on when the visitor comes back.

Comment: What kind of data you want to store in cookies?

Comment: That's obvious) Cookies can store plain text only. I meant more clarification on data you want to store

Comment: just the scores people achieve when using the timer. Let's say I get 18 sec,  I push that 18 sec in an array and insert the array to the cookie.

Comment: Such data as scores should be stored on **server**, not in cookies. Or you have to consider to use html5 localStorage instead of cookies.

Comment: how should I do this in js? I've never done that before ;/

Comment: To use localStorage start from [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API)